# How to have a an array bounded by an INDIRECT formula populate across?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am a working on a sheet for work that pulls totals for individual team members.

My current working Formula is

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT("'" & $A3 & "'!E$143:I$143"), "<>0%"), NA())
```

which references the team member named in column A and pulls an average of the weekly totals from row 143 of their personal sheet. My issue is that I am not sure how to make this auto populate across to refer to subsequent weeks J143:N143, O143:S143 etc etc. So each time I need the column refs moving by 5

I have tried researching the problem and found references to OFFSET and ROW formulas. But I am still very much learning my way around Excel and only recently found out about using INDIRECT to refer to named sheets. The various answers I have found dont seem to solve my particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below formula might work for you:

```
=LET(
     data,WRAPROWS(INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!E$143:X$143"),5),
     removed_zero,IFERROR(IFS(data>0,data),""),
     BYROW(removed_zero,LAMBDA(row,AVERAGE(row))))
```

Assuming your data is in `E$143:X$143`,

```
WRAPROWS(INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!E$143:X$143"),5)
```

will reshape your data into something like below:

[image: reshaped data]

```
IFERROR(IFS(data>0,data),"")
```

will remove zeros in your data.

Then `BYROW()` will calculate average for each row.

```
BYROW(removed_zero,LAMBDA(row,AVERAGE(row)))
```

Comment: This does look close to what I am trying to achieve. It's not formulas that I am familiar with so I am currently breaking it down to understand it.

My percentage totals data runs from E143 to GS143 with each column being a weekday for the rest of the year.  My apologies for this not being completely clear in the outset. My ultimate goal is to get a formula that pulls an average for each week of the year. I will have a tinker and try to familiarise myself with these.

Comment: Okay, some success with taking this code and tinkering with it to follow my needs just leaves me with one issue, when there are zeros for the weeks data it still results in a #DIV/0!
The following is what I have got now. changing WRAPROWS and BYROW to their column equivalents and expanding the data range
=LET(data,WRAPCOLS(INDIRECT("'"&$A3&"'!E$143:GS$143"),5), removed_zero,IFERROR(IFS(data>0,data),""), BYCOL(removed_zero,LAMBDA(row,AVERAGE(row))))

Comment: If you have #DIV/0 errors, then I think you need to tweak IFERROR(IFS(data>0,data),""). IFERROR(IFS(data>0,data),"") is making all numbers that are less than zero blank. (because Average() function ignore blank cells). I am not sure what your data looks like. but as long as you replace 0 or 0% with "", Average() can handle.